# Слияние двух массивов

Tags: php, массивы

Есть два массива:

```
[["902272","-360","somedata","somedata","","","","","","","02.03.2015",""],
["902273","-360","somedata","somedata","","","","","","","02.03.2015",""],
["902274","-360","somedata","somedata","","","","","","","02.03.2015",""],
["902275","-360","somedata","somedata","","","","","","","02.03.2015",""]]
```

и

```
[["902272", "240"],
["902273", "120"]]
```

Необходимо слить их с помощью PHP в первый массив, заполнив, к примеру, 5е значение(которое первое пустое), значениями из второго массива, но с условием, что если первое значение из первого массива не равно ни одному первому значению второго массива, то второе значение ставим 0, чтобы получить массив вида

```
[["902272","-360","somedata","somedata","240","","","","","","02.03.2015",""],
["902273","-360","somedata","somedata","120","","","","","","02.03.2015",""],
["902274","-360","somedata","somedata","0","","","","","","02.03.2015",""],
["902275","-360","somedata","somedata","0","","","","","","02.03.2015",""]]
```

Спасибо.

1 попытка:

```
$num = array();
foreach($csvfile as $r){ //Для каждой строчки csv
     $row = str_getcsv($r); //Получаем строку csv
     $number = $r[0]; //Первое значение - id(из таблицы)
     foreach($res[4] as $r2){ 
          if($r2[0] === $number) { //Если значение из второй таблицы совпадает со значением из первой
               $num[4][] = $r2[1]; //Выносим в переменную с полноценно заполненными значениями (с нулями) количество.
            }
            if(!array_search($r2[0], $ids2)){ //Если значения первой таблицы нет в массиве с id(предварительно зацепленном из первого массива)
                $num[4][] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Всё равно нулей нет.

Comment: Ваш алгоритм решения покажите пожалуйста. Точнее, попытки решения.

Comment: Прикрепил в топ.

Answer (score 1):

думаю слить не получится. Вам стоит использовать перебор массивов и подставление.
Если выделить первые значения как ключи массивов то можно использовать лишь подставление

```
$array =   [["902272","-360","somedata","somedata","","","","","","","02.03.2015",""],
    ["902273","-360","somedata","somedata","","","","","","","02.03.2015",""],
    ["902274","-360","somedata","somedata","","","","","","","02.03.2015",""],
    ["902275","-360","somedata","somedata","","","","","","","02.03.2015",""]];
    $array2 = [["902272", "240"],
    ["902273", "120"]];

    foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
        foreach ($array2 as $key2 => $value2) {
            if($value[0] == $value2[0])
                $value[4] = $value2[1];
                continue;
        }   
        if( empty($value[4])){
           $value[4] = 0;
        }
    }
    var_dump( $array);
```

Comment: не хватает "что если первое значение из первого массива не равно ни одному первому значению второго массива, то второе значение ставим 0" ;)

Comment: @Visman обновил)